# Reloading of ViewPager doesn't create first 3 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a SherlockFragment's based fragment which includes a ViewPager operating with Fragments via FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I implemented "infinite" scroll, so the adaptor returns getCount() 1000. It works. The problem occurs when I replace() the main fragment from the main activity with another data, onCreateView of this main fragment called like during the first initialization: I recreate adaptor and set it to the ViewPager, run notifyDataSetChanged() and set relevant view with setCurrentItem(). At this point I don't see the Fragment since getItem() is not called. In case I'm swiping the ViewPager left or right, the 3rd fragment from the middle is showed and then everything is working, i.e. getItem() is called only during the swiping:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timebar, container, false);      
    mPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.timebar_pager);
    mTitleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.timebar_titles);

    mPagerAdapter = new MyAdapter(container.getContext(), getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), mPager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
mPagerAdapter.setDate(mStartDate, mPagerAdapter.MIDDLE_POSITION);
    return view;
 }

 public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public final int FULL_COUNT = 1000;
    private final int MIDDLE_POSITION = FULL_COUNT/2;
    private long mMiddleFragmentDate;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ViewPager viewPager)
    {
      super(fragmentManager);
      mMiddleFragmentDate = mStartDate;
      mViewPager = viewPager;
    }

    public long getMiddlePosDate()
    {
      return mMiddleFragmentDate;
    }

    private void refreshData(int position)
    {
      Log.d("TIMEBAR","@@@@@ refreshData pos=" + position); 
      mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      View localView = mViewPager.findViewWithTag(Integer.valueOf(position));         
      if (localView != null)
      {
        Log.d("TIMEBAR","@@@@@ refreshData localView found & != null");  
        localView.invalidate();
      }
      mTitleIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Calendar getDateByPosition(int position)
    {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(mMiddleFragmentDate);       
      cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (position - MIDDLE_POSITION) * mNumOfDaysPerView);
      return cal;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position, Object object)
    {
      super.destroyItem(viewGroup, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
      return FULL_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
      GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar)getDateByPosition(position);
      return TimebarFragment.newInstance(position, cal.getTimeInMillis(), mNumOfDaysPerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object paramObject)
    {
      return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        Calendar cal = getDateByPosition(position);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(mCalendarUtils.getDayOfMonth(cal));
        sb.append(" ");
        if (mNumOfDaysPerView > 1) {
            sb.append(mCalendarUtils.getMonthNameShort(cal));
        } else {
            sb.append(mCalendarUtils.getMonthNameLong(cal));
        }
        if (mNumOfDaysPerView > 1) {
            sb.append(" - ");           
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, mNumOfDaysPerView - 1); 
            sb.append(mCalendarUtils.getDayOfMonth(cal));
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(mCalendarUtils.getMonthNameShort(cal));
        }           
        if (calNow.get(Calendar.YEAR) != cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        }               
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void setDate(long date, int position)
    {
      mMiddleFragmentDate = date;
      refreshData(position);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally using of **android-support-v13** library instead of **android-support-v4** library and using **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getSupportFragmentManager()** solved all these issues. Now:

- Reloading the main fragment causes reload of relevant Fragments in pager (onCreateView() is called)
- There is no problem to instantiate more than one instance of the ViewPager simultaneously.